# django admin The outermost 'atomic' block cannot use savepoint = False when autocommit is off

Tags: django, django-admin

When I try to delete an item from a table generated by django admin, it throws this error

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sybase_app/packageweight/?q=493

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'sybase_app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1590.                 response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_action
  1333.             response = func(self, request, queryset)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/actions.py" in delete_selected
  49.             queryset.delete()
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in delete
  537.         collector.delete()
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py" in delete
  282.         with transaction.atomic(using=self.using, savepoint=False):
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in __enter__
  164.                         "The outermost 'atomic' block cannot use "

Exception Type: TransactionManagementError at /admin/sybase_app/packageweight/
Exception Value: The outermost 'atomic' block cannot use savepoint = False when autocommit is off.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That restriction was removed in Django 1.8.5 (commit: [django/django@425c5e4](https://github.com/django/django/commit/425c5e40eae90bd3ee3633011ef97edb26858c94)).

However, the `Delete selected` feature still won't work when autocommit is off.

## 1. Restore autocommit if accidentally turned off

If you have `'AUTOCOMMIT': False` in settings.py, remove it and the feature should work.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'AUTOCOMMIT': False,  # Remove this line
    }
}
```

## 2. Patch the action with transaction.atomic

If you need autocommit off, patch `actions.delete_selected` in manage.py or an [`AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig).

```py
from django.contrib.admin import actions
from django.db import transaction
actions.delete_selected = transaction.atomic(actions.delete_selected)
```